# Can I have custom UILocalNotification repeat intervals (i.e. weekdays only?)

Tags: objective-c, weekday, localnotification, uilocalnotification

I would like to be able to schedule a UILocalNotification to repeat at the same time every day, but only on weekdays (no Saturdays or Sundays).  Is this possible using the repeat interval feature of UILocalNotification, or is my only option to create some kind of class that handles the time and date and works out when to schedule (several) notifications in advance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. Set the `repeatInterval` of the UILocalNotication to `NSWeekdayCalendarUnit`.

Here's [a list of available `repeatIntervals`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCalendarUnit).