# UILocalNotification Repeat Interval for Custom Alarm (sun, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uilocalnotification, nscalendar

I'm using `UILocalNotification` for Alarm Purpose. I have a custom option for repeat based on weekdays (sun, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat). So many applications did this process. I tried My level best. But I can't get it to work. Please you guys help me....

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot set custom repeat intervals with [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  This has been asked before (see below) but only limited options are provided.  The [repeatInterval parameter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/repeatInterval) is an enum type and it limited to [specific values](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCalendarUnit).

You cannot multiply those enumerations and get multiples of those intervals.  You cannot have more than 64 local notifications set in your app.  You cannot reschedule a notification once it fires unless the user chooses to run your app when the notification fires (they may not run it).

There is a request for repeat interval multipliers [posted here](http://openradar.appspot.com/8561927).  You can add comments to it.  I suggest filing a bug report or feature request (url?) with Apple.

- [How to set Local Notification repeat interval to custom time interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363847/how-to-set-local-notification-repeat-interval-to-custom-time-interval)
- [Custom repeat interval for UILocalNotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762517/custom-repeat-interval-for-uilocalnotification)
- [Custom UILocalNotification repeat interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678381/custom-uilocalnotification-repeat-interval)
- [UILocalNotification Repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581641/uilocalnotification-repeat)
- [non-fixed repeatInterval in UILocalNotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986595/non-fixed-repeatinterval-in-uilocalnotification)
- [Can I have custom UILocalNotification repeat intervals (i.e. weekdays only?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121121/can-i-have-custom-uilocalnotification-repeat-intervals-i-e-weekdays-only)
- [Repeating UILocalNotifications with Gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203920/repeating-uilocalnotifications-with-gaps)
- [Repeat UILocalNotification on certain days of week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938528/uilocalnotification-repeatinterval-on-days-of-week)

Comment: Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW5) says **an app can schedule 128 local notifications at the same time** : _Your own apps can have no more than 128 local notifications active at any given time, any of which can be configured to repeat at a specified interval._

Comment: @nburk The link in your comment no longer works. Do you happen to know if what you said is still accurate?

Comment: iOS 10 has a new repeating notification option with a custom time interval option + (instancetype)triggerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)timeInterval repeats:(BOOL)repeats;

Comment: @SteveMoser do you have a link to the docs? My Google results only show me how to trigger repeated but not with a certain starting point AND repeating interval.

Answer (score 2):

> Simply make a methods with parameters interval and weekday. And call
>   the function every time u have to set alarm.But the Notifications for
>   weekdays are to be settled separately.As I have called the method as
>   given below:

```
            [self notificationWithItem:tempDict Date:[self SetDateForAlarmWithWeekday:2 :tempDict] andRepeatInterval:NSWeekCalendarUnit];
            [self notificationWithItem:tempDict Date:[self SetDateForAlarmWithWeekday:3 :tempDict]andRepeatInterval:NSWeekCalendarUnit];
            [self notificationWithItem:tempDict Date:[self SetDateForAlarmWithWeekday:4 :tempDict] andRepeatInterval:NSWeekCalendarUnit];
            [self notificationWithItem:tempDict Date:[self SetDateForAlarmWithWeekday:5 :tempDict] andRepeatInterval:NSWeekCalendarUnit];
            [self notificationWithItem:tempDict Date:[self SetDateForAlarmWithWeekday:6 :tempDict] andRepeatInterval:NSWeekCalendarUnit];
```

> I passed weekday parameter for different days of week as 2 for
>   monday,3 for tuesday and so on.
>
> ```
> I hope it will help u...!
> ```