# iOS local notification customization

Tags: xcode, uilocalnotification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UILocalNotification Repeat Interval for Custom Alarm (sun, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966365/uilocalnotification-repeat-interval-for-custom-alarm-sun-mon-tue-wed-thu-f)

i am new in Xcode. I need to use local notifications in my app. Local notification has property repeatinterval which can have only limited values (repeat every minute, hour, day, etc). But i need to have  notifications to repeat in more flexible way (for example: 3 times a day). Is there a way to do this??

Comment: Also see a list of duplicates [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6966665/900873).

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this quite thoroughly myself about a month ago.  You can only get automatic repeats at single `repeatInterval` intervals - every one minute, or hour, or day, etc.  If you want any finer control you have to do it yourself.  Since you want notifications thrice a day, schedule three notifications, eight, 16, and 24 hours hence, each on a one-day repeat.