# Show UILocalNotification at periodic time interval

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I want to create a `UILocalNotification` (a location notification reminder) which will run with a periodic time interval. For example if I create a local reminder with time say `2013-12-12 12:00:00` and if I set the time interval with 5 minute then this local reminder should notify me every 5 minutes from scheduled time.

Comment: Have you tried NSTimer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UILocalNotification Repeat Interval for Custom Alarm (sun, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966365/uilocalnotification-repeat-interval-for-custom-alarm-sun-mon-tue-wed-thu-f)

Answer (score 0):

[`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) does not have any option to set a time interval for every 5 minutes. You can only specify a [`NSCalendarUnit`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCalendarUnit) for the [`repeatInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW3) property.

The best option is to make several [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) every 5 min. past the reminder and set the [`repeatInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW3) on `NSHourCalendarUnit` to make them repeat every hour.

[`repeatInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW3) documentation:

> If you assign a calendar unit such as weekly (NSWeekCalendarUnit) or
>   yearly (NSYearCalendarUnit), the system reschedules the notification
>   for delivery at the specified interval. The default value is 0, which
>   means don't repeat.

Comment: So it should be notification.repeatInterval = 5*NSMinuteCalendarUnit, right?

Comment: No, you can **NOT** set a custom `repeatInterval` only values from the `NSCalendarUnit` are accepted.

Comment: In the Apple iOS documentation linked in my answer and many other answer to this same question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966365/uilocalnotification-repeat-interval-for-custom-alarm-sun-mon-tue-wed-thu-f

Comment: Nor is it stated that it will work, the type of the property says it all: `NSCalendarUnit` not `NSTimeInterval`!