# Schedule a local notification for a specific time in Swift 2

Tags: xcode, notifications, uilocalnotification, swift2

I've been all over these forums and other sites and I keep getting pieces of an answer that don't add up. Essentially, I would like to create a notification that fires, for example, every weekday at 6:28 AM, 12:28 PM, and 5:28 PM.

I have pieces of a solution, but I'm really unsure where to go. Am I setting this up right at all? Any help is appreciated.

```
let notification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
notification.category = "News and Sports"
notification.alertAction = "get caught up with the world"
notification.alertBody = "LIVE news and sports on VIC in just a minute!"
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Preparing to show local notifications requires 2 main steps:

### Step 1

On iOS 8+ your app must ask and, subsequently, be granted permission by the user to display local notifications. Asking permission can be done as follows in your AppDelegate.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    ...
    if #available(iOS 8, *) {
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Sound, .Alert, .Badge], categories: nil))
    }

    return true
}
```

**Do not call `registerUserNotificationSettings(_:)` when your app is running on a pre-iOS 8 operating system. Otherwise, your app will crash at runtime.** Luckily, this shouldn't be a problem since you're working with Swift 2.

### Step 2

Schedule your notification at a future `fireDate`.

```
let notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
...
... // set the notification's category, alertAction, alertBody, etc.
...
notification.fireDate = ... // set to a future date
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Unfortunately, according to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6966665/5007059) by @progrmr,

> You cannot set custom repeat intervals with [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  This has been asked before (see below) but
>   only limited options are provided.  The [repeatInterval parameter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/repeatInterval)
>   is an enum type and it limited to [specific values](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCalendarUnit).
>
> You cannot multiply those enumerations and get multiples of those
>   intervals.  You cannot have more than 64 local notifications set in
>   your app.  You cannot reschedule a notification once it fires unless
>   the user chooses to run your app when the notification fires (they may
>   not run it).
>
> There is a request for repeat interval multipliers [posted here](http://openradar.appspot.com/8561927). 
>   You can add comments to it.  I suggest filing a bug report or feature
>   request (url?) with Apple.

Many other Stack Overflow answers confirm the claims in the quotes above. Visit the link to the full quoted answer, which contains a list of supporting answers.

A potential workaround for your case would be to schedule 3 local notifications. Set each one to fire at 6:28 AM, 12:28 PM, and 5:28 PM, respectively. Then, set the `repeatInterval` of all 3 local notifications to `.CalendarUnitWeekday`.