# How to fire a notification X minutes from now?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I want to be able to hit a button that says "1 minute from now" or "1 hour from now" and have a notification go off (push / banner). How do I go about doing this?

Comment: post the notification using performSelector after delay!

Comment: @Teja Nandamuri - but what if the app is not in the foreground in a hour from now? Then the performSelector would not execute. noobprogrammer, I'm sure you can easily find the documentation for how to create a notification or a past question on it. It is possible to set the time that the notification fires.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Schedule a local notification for a specific time in Swift 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31043458/schedule-a-local-notification-for-a-specific-time-in-swift-2)

Answer (score 1):

set your timer according to button click if 1 min or 1 hr using the following command

```
 NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(time, target: self, selector: #selector(functionName), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

then broadcast the notification in that function like shown below

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("youFunctionName", object: nil)
```

addobserver in viewcontroller in which you want to receive notification

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(youFunctionName), name: "youFunctionName", object: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, have written code to schedule local notification :

```
//First register for User Settings if iOS8 or above
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
...
     if #available(iOS 8, *) {
          application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Sound, .Alert, .Badge], categories: nil))
     }
...
return true
}

//Function to schedule the local notification
func scheduleNotificationWithInterval(secondsAfter:Double, notificationTitle title:String, notificationBody body:String) {

     let fireDate = NSDate()

     let localNotif = UILocalNotification()

     localNotif.fireDate = fireDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(secondsAfter)

     localNotif.alertBody = body

     if #available(iOS 8.2, *) {
          localNotif.alertTitle = title
     }

     localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
     localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

     UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotif)

}
```

Hope it helps :]