# Repeat Interval for UILocalNotification every 10s

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate, uilocalnotification

I want to make the **`UILocalNotification`** with the date user selected, but if user does not tap on the Notification bar to launch app, will continue to push the Local notification after 10s. That means the app will push the 2 Local notifications:

1. The main Local notification with the date time user selected
2. The repeat local notification every 10s.

**I tried this code but it's not work:**

```
UILocalNotification *reminderNote = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
reminderNote.fireDate = _selectedDate;
reminderNote.repeatInterval = NSSecondCalendarUnit;
reminderNote.alertBody = @"some text";
reminderNote.alertAction = @"View";
reminderNote.soundName = @"sound.aif";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:reminderNote];

reminderNote.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:reminderNote];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would delete the app if it kept hassling me like that.

Comment: me too, i'm not a massive fan of weekly reminders to use an app...

Comment: same here... 10 sec?...

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things wrong with this:

1. You cannot repeat `UILocalNotification`'s that frequently. From the Apple documentation:

> Note that intervals of less than one minute are not supported.

2. You can only repeat by standard `NSCalendarUnit` intervals, like every hour, every day, or every month. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6966665/5644794) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create separate object for `UILocalNotification`

create 2 different UILocalNotification object and fire it at different time

like

```
-(void) fireAtDate:(NSDate *) date {

    UILocalNotification *reminderNote = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    reminderNote.fireDate = _selectedDate;
    reminderNote.repeatInterval = NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    reminderNote.alertBody = @"some text";
    reminderNote.alertAction = @"View";
    reminderNote.soundName = @"sound.aif";


    reminderNote.fireDate = date;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:reminderNote];
}
```

...

```
[self fireDate([NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0])];
[self fireDate([NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10])];
```